# .htaccess / url rewrite issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

Using CakePHP. The website is www.villapalmeras.co.uk. When I view the root my links appear correctly (ie http://www.villapalmeras.co.uk/public/events). When I navigate to any other page, the same link then shows as http://www.villapalmeras.co.uk/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage25/jo/rd/an/jordanwallwork.co.uk/public_html/domains/villalaspalmeras/public/events

I'm using a 123-reg hosting package, and have mapped the villapalmeras.co.uk domain to the location domains/villapalmeras (the root of this is my website at jordanwallwork.co.uk). Tried editing .htaccesses files with no success.

My .htaccess files are:

/domains/villapalmeras/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/domains/villapalmeras/app/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/domains/villapalmeras/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php:

```
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
}

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

Comment: can you post the ROOT, APP_DIR, and CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH from your index.php please? If those are configured properly, you shouldn't need to mess with the .htaccesses.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer was really simple! All I needed to do was add `RewriteBase /` to all of the .htaccess files, not just the root, and then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify my comment above, the code you want to modify might be in your index.php:

The code you are looking for:

```
/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
    if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
        define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
    }
```

It should be changed to something more like:

```
/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', DS . 'home' . DS . 'username');
    }
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
    if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
        define('APP_DIR', 'domain.com');
    }
/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'home' . DS . 'username');
    }
```

Depending of course on the structure of your hosts directories.

Comment: I really want to upvote this, but your rep points are 777! I just can't!

Comment: dont do it! I will lose permissions! Not to mention the adverse effects on my luck.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even realised that there were configurable settings in that file!! I'll have a look, but also I've included what the settings currently are in case you can spot the problem

Comment: try doing a die(debug()); on the variable strings making up the paths and see if they actually make the proper path to your app, to your app's webroot, etc. Everything may check out, but doing this should hopefully give you a good idea of if these paths are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change each .htaccess and doesn't need to change in index.php or other files.

```
/domains/villapalmeras/.htaccess:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

/domains/villapalmeras/app/.htaccess:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

/domains/villapalmeras/app/webroot/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```